# JOptionPane goes away after reader

Tags: java

I'm doing a double input on a `JOptionePane` to calculate the area of a rectangle. So i need the user to put the `length` then the `width`. However, after the first input, i put a reader right after and the second `JOptionPane` for the width doesnt pop up. I realize this needs alot of work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Project3_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader =  new Scanner(System.in);  
        int length;
        int width;
        int surfacearea;

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the edge: ");
        length = reader.nextInt();  // doesnt work past this
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of the edge: ");
        width = reader.nextInt();

        surfacearea = length * width;

        JFrame someFrame = new JFrame();    // how to insert surfacearea??
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        someFrame.add(label);
        someFrame.setSize(230, 230);
        someFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? or what do you want?

Comment: @Yohannes question is why it doesn't take 2nd input :)

Comment: See minigeek's answer below. Also, what do you mean by "insert surface area"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the ways to input data to your program. Let's begin:

`Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);`

The line above allows you to catch data in the command line from the keyboard.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of edge: ");
```

This Option Pane is showing correctly, you put a value and then nothing happens. This is because your program is waiting to input something in the **command line**

```
length=reader.nextInt();
```

When your program arrives to the line above, the **`reader.nextInt()` *stops the program until you put something in the command line.***

The **correct way** should be something like this:

```
length = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the edge: "));
width = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of the edge:"));
```

And remove:

```
length = reader.nextInt();
width = reader.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to process the input of the `JOptionPane` like this:

```
String inputLength = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the edge: ");
int length = Integer.parseInt(inputLength);
```

Remove the `Scanner` because he is waiting for input in the console.

Comment: I think that you misunderstand the variables `width` and `length` which probably have nothing to do with the size of the `JFrame` but are part of the assignment to do a calculation.

Comment: True i'll delete this part